# Converting country codes in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, locale, globalization, iso

In .NET is there any way to convert from three letter country codes (defined in ISO 3166-1 alpha-3) to two letter language codes (defined in ISO 3166-1 alpha-2)  eg. convert BEL to BE?

Have looked at the RegionInfo class in System.Globalization but the constructor does not seem to support the three letter codes.

Comment: This question contradicts itself. The ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 standard is for countries whereas the question refers to them as language codes. Bear that in mind when reading the answers.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `RegionInfo` class does know the three-letter code (in the [`ThreeLetterISORegionName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.threeletterisoregionname.aspx) property), but I don’t think there is a way to get `RegionInfo` based on this code, you would need to enumerate all regions and add them to your own dictionary, with the three-letter code as a key.

However, I think the .NET Framework uses `RegionInfo` to work with *cultures*, not countries in the ISO 3166-1 sense. Therefore, many countries from the ISO 3166-1 standard are not available (try e.g. `SX`). I guess you should create your own country codebook.

**Edit:** From 246 countries in my current country codebook, `RegionInfo` is available for 125 of them, the rest (121) are not supported. Conclusion: This is not a good way to get a country codebook.

Answer (score 42):

Looks like there is no built-in way to do that. You can use the approach from the [GenericTypeTea's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884692/converting-country-codes-in-net/4884803#4884803). But if you need to convert many country codes you can avoid Cultures enumeration and pre-compute a mapping dictionary for country codes conversion.

That's how such generator looks like:

```
namespace ISOCountryCodes
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var countryCodesMapping = new Dictionary<string, RegionInfo>();
            CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);

            foreach (var culture in cultures)
            {
                try
                {
                    var region = new RegionInfo(culture.LCID);
                    countryCodesMapping[region.ThreeLetterISORegionName] = region;
                }
                catch (CultureNotFoundException)
                {
                    var consoleColor = Console.ForegroundColor;

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Culture not found: " + culture.Name);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = consoleColor;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("var countryCodesMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>() {");
            foreach (var mapping in countryCodesMapping.OrderBy(mapping => mapping.Key))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("   {{ \"{0}\", \"{1}\" }},    // {2}", mapping.Key, mapping.Value.TwoLetterISORegionName, mapping.Value.EnglishName);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("};");
        }
    }
}
```

Run this generator to get a country codes mapping dictionary like this:

```
var countryCodesMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
   { "AFG", "AF" },    // Afghanistan
   { "ALB", "AL" },    // Albania
   { "ARE", "AE" },    // U.A.E.
   { "ARG", "AR" },    // Argentina
   { "ARM", "AM" },    // Armenia
   { "AUS", "AU" },    // Australia
   { "AUT", "AT" },    // Austria
   { "AZE", "AZ" },    // Azerbaijan
   { "BEL", "BE" },    // Belgium
   { "BGD", "BD" },    // Bangladesh
   { "BGR", "BG" },    // Bulgaria
   { "BHR", "BH" },    // Bahrain
   { "BIH", "BA" },    // Bosnia and Herzegovina
   { "BLR", "BY" },    // Belarus
   { "BLZ", "BZ" },    // Belize
   { "BOL", "BO" },    // Bolivia
   { "BRA", "BR" },    // Brazil
   { "BRN", "BN" },    // Brunei Darussalam
   { "CAN", "CA" },    // Canada
   { "CHE", "CH" },    // Switzerland
   { "CHL", "CL" },    // Chile
   { "CHN", "CN" },    // People's Republic of China
   { "COL", "CO" },    // Colombia
   { "CRI", "CR" },    // Costa Rica
   { "CZE", "CZ" },    // Czech Republic
   { "DEU", "DE" },    // Germany
   { "DNK", "DK" },    // Denmark
   { "DOM", "DO" },    // Dominican Republic
   { "DZA", "DZ" },    // Algeria
   { "ECU", "EC" },    // Ecuador
   { "EGY", "EG" },    // Egypt
   { "ESP", "ES" },    // Spain
   { "EST", "EE" },    // Estonia
   { "ETH", "ET" },    // Ethiopia
   { "FIN", "FI" },    // Finland
   { "FRA", "FR" },    // France
   { "FRO", "FO" },    // Faroe Islands
   { "GBR", "GB" },    // United Kingdom
   { "GEO", "GE" },    // Georgia
   { "GRC", "GR" },    // Greece
   { "GRL", "GL" },    // Greenland
   { "GTM", "GT" },    // Guatemala
   { "HKG", "HK" },    // Hong Kong S.A.R.
   { "HND", "HN" },    // Honduras
   { "HRV", "HR" },    // Croatia
   { "HUN", "HU" },    // Hungary
   { "IDN", "ID" },    // Indonesia
   { "IND", "IN" },    // India
   { "IRL", "IE" },    // Ireland
   { "IRN", "IR" },    // Iran
   { "IRQ", "IQ" },    // Iraq
   { "ISL", "IS" },    // Iceland
   { "ISR", "IL" },    // Israel
   { "ITA", "IT" },    // Italy
   { "JAM", "JM" },    // Jamaica
   { "JOR", "JO" },    // Jordan
   { "JPN", "JP" },    // Japan
   { "KAZ", "KZ" },    // Kazakhstan
   { "KEN", "KE" },    // Kenya
   { "KGZ", "KG" },    // Kyrgyzstan
   { "KHM", "KH" },    // Cambodia
   { "KOR", "KR" },    // Korea
   { "KWT", "KW" },    // Kuwait
   { "LAO", "LA" },    // Lao P.D.R.
   { "LBN", "LB" },    // Lebanon
   { "LBY", "LY" },    // Libya
   { "LIE", "LI" },    // Liechtenstein
   { "LKA", "LK" },    // Sri Lanka
   { "LTU", "LT" },    // Lithuania
   { "LUX", "LU" },    // Luxembourg
   { "LVA", "LV" },    // Latvia
   { "MAC", "MO" },    // Macao S.A.R.
   { "MAR", "MA" },    // Morocco
   { "MCO", "MC" },    // Principality of Monaco
   { "MDV", "MV" },    // Maldives
   { "MEX", "MX" },    // Mexico
   { "MKD", "MK" },    // Macedonia (FYROM)
   { "MLT", "MT" },    // Malta
   { "MNE", "ME" },    // Montenegro
   { "MNG", "MN" },    // Mongolia
   { "MYS", "MY" },    // Malaysia
   { "NGA", "NG" },    // Nigeria
   { "NIC", "NI" },    // Nicaragua
   { "NLD", "NL" },    // Netherlands
   { "NOR", "NO" },    // Norway
   { "NPL", "NP" },    // Nepal
   { "NZL", "NZ" },    // New Zealand
   { "OMN", "OM" },    // Oman
   { "PAK", "PK" },    // Islamic Republic of Pakistan
   { "PAN", "PA" },    // Panama
   { "PER", "PE" },    // Peru
   { "PHL", "PH" },    // Republic of the Philippines
   { "POL", "PL" },    // Poland
   { "PRI", "PR" },    // Puerto Rico
   { "PRT", "PT" },    // Portugal
   { "PRY", "PY" },    // Paraguay
   { "QAT", "QA" },    // Qatar
   { "ROU", "RO" },    // Romania
   { "RUS", "RU" },    // Russia
   { "RWA", "RW" },    // Rwanda
   { "SAU", "SA" },    // Saudi Arabia
   { "SCG", "CS" },    // Serbia and Montenegro (Former)
   { "SEN", "SN" },    // Senegal
   { "SGP", "SG" },    // Singapore
   { "SLV", "SV" },    // El Salvador
   { "SRB", "RS" },    // Serbia
   { "SVK", "SK" },    // Slovakia
   { "SVN", "SI" },    // Slovenia
   { "SWE", "SE" },    // Sweden
   { "SYR", "SY" },    // Syria
   { "TAJ", "TJ" },    // Tajikistan
   { "THA", "TH" },    // Thailand
   { "TKM", "TM" },    // Turkmenistan
   { "TTO", "TT" },    // Trinidad and Tobago
   { "TUN", "TN" },    // Tunisia
   { "TUR", "TR" },    // Turkey
   { "TWN", "TW" },    // Taiwan
   { "UKR", "UA" },    // Ukraine
   { "URY", "UY" },    // Uruguay
   { "USA", "US" },    // United States
   { "UZB", "UZ" },    // Uzbekistan
   { "VEN", "VE" },    // Bolivarian Republic of Venezuela
   { "VNM", "VN" },    // Vietnam
   { "YEM", "YE" },    // Yemen
   { "ZAF", "ZA" },    // South Africa
   { "ZWE", "ZW" },    // Zimbabwe
};
```

Answer (score 25):

**UPDATED:**

Didn't read the question properly before. The following *should* now be correctly converting from ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 to ISO 3166-1 alpha-2:

---

There's no built in way of doing it. You'll need to iterate through the `CultureInfo`s to get the `RegionInfo`s in order to manually find the match (this is pretty ineffecient so some caching would be advisable):

```
public string ConvertThreeLetterNameToTwoLetterName(string name)
{
    if (name.Length != 3)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("name must be three letters.");
    }

    name = name.ToUpper();

    CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
    foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
    {
        RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(culture.LCID);
        if (region.ThreeLetterISORegionName.ToUpper() == name)
        {
            return region.TwoLetterISORegionName;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: OK, it is better now, and gives _almost_ identical results as my test below. The interesting thing is that this does not work for Tajikistan – `new RegionInfo("TJ")` works but your code returns `null` for `"TJK"`.

Comment: @Mormegil - There's a few others I've noticed that seem to return null. Must be because of `SpecificCultures`. I'm investigating.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - I know _many_ of them return null, see my post below: for 121 countries, there is no RegionInfo available in the .NET Framework at all. Tajikistan is interesting because there _is_ a RegionInfo for it, but your code does not work for it. SpecificCultures does not have anything to do with it, the data is simply not there at all.

Comment: @Mormegil - `new RegionInfo("TJ")` fails on my machine. I hate Cultures, never have understood them.

Comment: Where are only 210 regions, some are missing e.g. Cyprus.

Comment: Or: `var twoLetterCountryCode = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Select(ci => new RegionInfo(ci.LCID)).FirstOrDefault(r => r.ThreeLetterISORegionName.Equals(threeLetterCountryCode, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                                    ?.TwoLetterISORegionName;`

Answer (score 20):

I just strung this quick and dirty class together to query and manage ISO3166-1 entries. There is just one example method there to query by alpha 3 code, but should be simple enough to add other conversions as required.

example usage:

```
string countryName = ISO3166.FromAlpha3("LUX").Name;
```

class:

```
public static class ISO3166
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Obtain ISO3166-1 Country based on its alpha3 code.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="alpha3"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ISO3166Country FromAlpha3(string alpha3)
    {
        Collection<ISO3166Country> collection = BuildCollection();
        return collection.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Alpha3 == alpha3);
    }

    #region Build Collection
    private static Collection<ISO3166Country> BuildCollection()
    {
        Collection<ISO3166Country> collection = new Collection<ISO3166Country>();

        // This collection built from Wikipedia entry on ISO3166-1 on 9th Feb 2016

        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Afghanistan", "AF", "AFG", 4));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Åland Islands", "AX", "ALA", 248));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Albania", "AL", "ALB", 8));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Algeria", "DZ", "DZA", 12));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("American Samoa", "AS", "ASM", 16));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Andorra", "AD", "AND", 20));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Angola", "AO", "AGO", 24));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Anguilla", "AI", "AIA", 660));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Antarctica", "AQ", "ATA", 10));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Antigua and Barbuda", "AG", "ATG", 28));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Argentina", "AR", "ARG", 32));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Armenia", "AM", "ARM", 51));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Aruba", "AW", "ABW", 533));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Australia", "AU", "AUS", 36));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Austria", "AT", "AUT", 40));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Azerbaijan", "AZ", "AZE", 31));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Bahamas", "BS", "BHS", 44));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Bahrain", "BH", "BHR", 48));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Bangladesh", "BD", "BGD", 50));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Barbados", "BB", "BRB", 52));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Belarus", "BY", "BLR", 112));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Belgium", "BE", "BEL", 56));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Belize", "BZ", "BLZ", 84));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Benin", "BJ", "BEN", 204));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Bermuda", "BM", "BMU", 60));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Bhutan", "BT", "BTN", 64));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", "BO", "BOL", 68));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba", "BQ", "BES", 535));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Bosnia and Herzegovina", "BA", "BIH", 70));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Botswana", "BW", "BWA", 72));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Bouvet Island", "BV", "BVT", 74));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Brazil", "BR", "BRA", 76));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("British Indian Ocean Territory", "IO", "IOT", 86));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Brunei Darussalam", "BN", "BRN", 96));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Bulgaria", "BG", "BGR", 100));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Burkina Faso", "BF", "BFA", 854));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Burundi", "BI", "BDI", 108));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Cabo Verde", "CV", "CPV", 132));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Cambodia", "KH", "KHM", 116));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Cameroon", "CM", "CMR", 120));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Canada", "CA", "CAN", 124));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Cayman Islands", "KY", "CYM", 136));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Central African Republic", "CF", "CAF", 140));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Chad", "TD", "TCD", 148));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Chile", "CL", "CHL", 152));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("China", "CN", "CHN", 156));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Christmas Island", "CX", "CXR", 162));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "CC", "CCK", 166));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Colombia", "CO", "COL", 170));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Comoros", "KM", "COM", 174));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Congo", "CG", "COG", 178));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Congo (Democratic Republic of the)", "CD", "COD", 180));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Cook Islands", "CK", "COK", 184));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Costa Rica", "CR", "CRI", 188));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Côte d'Ivoire", "CI", "CIV", 384));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Croatia", "HR", "HRV", 191));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Cuba", "CU", "CUB", 192));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Curaçao", "CW", "CUW", 531));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Cyprus", "CY", "CYP", 196));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Czech Republic", "CZ", "CZE", 203));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Denmark", "DK", "DNK", 208));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Djibouti", "DJ", "DJI", 262));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Dominica", "DM", "DMA", 212));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Dominican Republic", "DO", "DOM", 214));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Ecuador", "EC", "ECU", 218));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Egypt", "EG", "EGY", 818));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("El Salvador", "SV", "SLV", 222));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Equatorial Guinea", "GQ", "GNQ", 226));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Eritrea", "ER", "ERI", 232));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Estonia", "EE", "EST", 233));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Ethiopia", "ET", "ETH", 231));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "FK", "FLK", 238));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Faroe Islands", "FO", "FRO", 234));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Fiji", "FJ", "FJI", 242));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Finland", "FI", "FIN", 246));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("France", "FR", "FRA", 250));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("French Guiana", "GF", "GUF", 254));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("French Polynesia", "PF", "PYF", 258));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("French Southern Territories", "TF", "ATF", 260));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Gabon", "GA", "GAB", 266));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Gambia", "GM", "GMB", 270));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Georgia", "GE", "GEO", 268));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Germany", "DE", "DEU", 276));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Ghana", "GH", "GHA", 288));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Gibraltar", "GI", "GIB", 292));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Greece", "GR", "GRC", 300));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Greenland", "GL", "GRL", 304));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Grenada", "GD", "GRD", 308));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Guadeloupe", "GP", "GLP", 312));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Guam", "GU", "GUM", 316));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Guatemala", "GT", "GTM", 320));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Guernsey", "GG", "GGY", 831));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Guinea", "GN", "GIN", 324));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Guinea-Bissau", "GW", "GNB", 624));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Guyana", "GY", "GUY", 328));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Haiti", "HT", "HTI", 332));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "HM", "HMD", 334));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Holy See", "VA", "VAT", 336));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Honduras", "HN", "HND", 340));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Hong Kong", "HK", "HKG", 344));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Hungary", "HU", "HUN", 348));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Iceland", "IS", "ISL", 352));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("India", "IN", "IND", 356));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Indonesia", "ID", "IDN", 360));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "IR", "IRN", 364));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Iraq", "IQ", "IRQ", 368));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Ireland", "IE", "IRL", 372));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Isle of Man", "IM", "IMN", 833));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Israel", "IL", "ISR", 376));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Italy", "IT", "ITA", 380));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Jamaica", "JM", "JAM", 388));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Japan", "JP", "JPN", 392));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Jersey", "JE", "JEY", 832));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Jordan", "JO", "JOR", 400));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Kazakhstan", "KZ", "KAZ", 398));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Kenya", "KE", "KEN", 404));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Kiribati", "KI", "KIR", 296));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Korea (Democratic People's Republic of)", "KP", "PRK", 408));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Korea (Republic of)", "KR", "KOR", 410));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Kuwait", "KW", "KWT", 414));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Kyrgyzstan", "KG", "KGZ", 417));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Lao People's Democratic Republic", "LA", "LAO", 418));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Latvia", "LV", "LVA", 428));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Lebanon", "LB", "LBN", 422));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Lesotho", "LS", "LSO", 426));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Liberia", "LR", "LBR", 430));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Libya", "LY", "LBY", 434));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Liechtenstein", "LI", "LIE", 438));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Lithuania", "LT", "LTU", 440));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Luxembourg", "LU", "LUX", 442));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Macao", "MO", "MAC", 446));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Macedonia (the former Yugoslav Republic of)", "MK", "MKD", 807));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Madagascar", "MG", "MDG", 450));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Malawi", "MW", "MWI", 454));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Malaysia", "MY", "MYS", 458));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Maldives", "MV", "MDV", 462));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Mali", "ML", "MLI", 466));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Malta", "MT", "MLT", 470));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Marshall Islands", "MH", "MHL", 584));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Martinique", "MQ", "MTQ", 474));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Mauritania", "MR", "MRT", 478));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Mauritius", "MU", "MUS", 480));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Mayotte", "YT", "MYT", 175));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Mexico", "MX", "MEX", 484));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Micronesia (Federated States of)", "FM", "FSM", 583));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Moldova (Republic of)", "MD", "MDA", 498));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Monaco", "MC", "MCO", 492));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Mongolia", "MN", "MNG", 496));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Montenegro", "ME", "MNE", 499));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Montserrat", "MS", "MSR", 500));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Morocco", "MA", "MAR", 504));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Mozambique", "MZ", "MOZ", 508));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Myanmar", "MM", "MMR", 104));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Namibia", "NA", "NAM", 516));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Nauru", "NR", "NRU", 520));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Nepal", "NP", "NPL", 524));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Netherlands", "NL", "NLD", 528));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("New Caledonia", "NC", "NCL", 540));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("New Zealand", "NZ", "NZL", 554));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Nicaragua", "NI", "NIC", 558));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Niger", "NE", "NER", 562));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Nigeria", "NG", "NGA", 566));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Niue", "NU", "NIU", 570));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Norfolk Island", "NF", "NFK", 574));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Northern Mariana Islands", "MP", "MNP", 580));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Norway", "NO", "NOR", 578));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Oman", "OM", "OMN", 512));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Pakistan", "PK", "PAK", 586));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Palau", "PW", "PLW", 585));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Palestine, State of", "PS", "PSE", 275));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Panama", "PA", "PAN", 591));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Papua New Guinea", "PG", "PNG", 598));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Paraguay", "PY", "PRY", 600));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Peru", "PE", "PER", 604));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Philippines", "PH", "PHL", 608));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Pitcairn", "PN", "PCN", 612));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Poland", "PL", "POL", 616));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Portugal", "PT", "PRT", 620));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Puerto Rico", "PR", "PRI", 630));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Qatar", "QA", "QAT", 634));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Réunion", "RE", "REU", 638));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Romania", "RO", "ROU", 642));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Russian Federation", "RU", "RUS", 643));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Rwanda", "RW", "RWA", 646));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Saint Barthélemy", "BL", "BLM", 652));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha", "SH", "SHN", 654));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Saint Kitts and Nevis", "KN", "KNA", 659));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Saint Lucia", "LC", "LCA", 662));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Saint Martin (French part)", "MF", "MAF", 663));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "PM", "SPM", 666));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "VC", "VCT", 670));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Samoa", "WS", "WSM", 882));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("San Marino", "SM", "SMR", 674));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Sao Tome and Principe", "ST", "STP", 678));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Saudi Arabia", "SA", "SAU", 682));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Senegal", "SN", "SEN", 686));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Serbia", "RS", "SRB", 688));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Seychelles", "SC", "SYC", 690));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Sierra Leone", "SL", "SLE", 694));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Singapore", "SG", "SGP", 702));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Sint Maarten (Dutch part)", "SX", "SXM", 534));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Slovakia", "SK", "SVK", 703));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Slovenia", "SI", "SVN", 705));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Solomon Islands", "SB", "SLB", 90));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Somalia", "SO", "SOM", 706));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("South Africa", "ZA", "ZAF", 710));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "GS", "SGS", 239));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("South Sudan", "SS", "SSD", 728));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Spain", "ES", "ESP", 724));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Sri Lanka", "LK", "LKA", 144));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Sudan", "SD", "SDN", 729));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Suriname", "SR", "SUR", 740));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "SJ", "SJM", 744));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Swaziland", "SZ", "SWZ", 748));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Sweden", "SE", "SWE", 752));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Switzerland", "CH", "CHE", 756));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Syrian Arab Republic", "SY", "SYR", 760));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Taiwan, Province of China[a]", "TW", "TWN", 158));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Tajikistan", "TJ", "TJK", 762));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Tanzania, United Republic of", "TZ", "TZA", 834));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Thailand", "TH", "THA", 764));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Timor-Leste", "TL", "TLS", 626));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Togo", "TG", "TGO", 768));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Tokelau", "TK", "TKL", 772));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Tonga", "TO", "TON", 776));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Trinidad and Tobago", "TT", "TTO", 780));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Tunisia", "TN", "TUN", 788));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Turkey", "TR", "TUR", 792));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Turkmenistan", "TM", "TKM", 795));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Turks and Caicos Islands", "TC", "TCA", 796));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Tuvalu", "TV", "TUV", 798));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Uganda", "UG", "UGA", 800));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Ukraine", "UA", "UKR", 804));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("United Arab Emirates", "AE", "ARE", 784));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "GB", "GBR", 826));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("United States of America", "US", "USA", 840));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("United States Minor Outlying Islands", "UM", "UMI", 581));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Uruguay", "UY", "URY", 858));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Uzbekistan", "UZ", "UZB", 860));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Vanuatu", "VU", "VUT", 548));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", "VE", "VEN", 862));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Viet Nam", "VN", "VNM", 704));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Virgin Islands (British)", "VG", "VGB", 92));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Virgin Islands (U.S.)", "VI", "VIR", 850));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Wallis and Futuna", "WF", "WLF", 876));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Western Sahara", "EH", "ESH", 732));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Yemen", "YE", "YEM", 887));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Zambia", "ZM", "ZMB", 894));
        collection.Add(new ISO3166Country("Zimbabwe", "ZW", "ZWE", 716));

        return collection;
    }
    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// Representation of an ISO3166-1 Country
/// </summary>
public class ISO3166Country
{
    public ISO3166Country(string name, string alpha2, string alpha3, int numericCode)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Alpha2 = alpha2;
        this.Alpha3 = alpha3;
        this.NumericCode = numericCode;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public string Alpha2 { get; private set; }

    public string Alpha3 { get; private set; }

    public int NumericCode { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Damn, that's indeed pretty dirty :O instead of dropping them in a collection one by one I'd rather initialise an array with them all at once, OR even put them all in your database (with the right dose of indexes and caching this sounds the way to go, right?). Not sure yet which is the best way to tackle this issue, so I'm open for suggestions...

Answer (score 10):

Some of the above answers are O(N) for lookups, which is fine if you're only doing it once, but generally you'll want to call this more than once per process in which case you'll probably want something more efficient.

```
var Iso3ToIso2Mapping = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
  .Select(ci => new RegionInfo(ci.LCID))
  .GroupBy(ri => ri.ThreeLetterISORegionName)
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().TwoLetterISORegionName);
```

Then you can just do a lookup with:

```
var iso2CountryCode = Iso3ToIso2Mapping["AUS"];
Console.WriteLine(iso2CountryCode);
```

Prints:

```
AU
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility that has not been mentioned here yet is my project `Nager.Country` that I make available on [GitHub](https://github.com/nager/Nager.Country) and also on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.Country/). It is available for .net 4.6 and .net standard 2.0

This problem could be solved like this

```cs
ICountryProvider countryProvider = new CountryProvider();
var countryInfo = countryProvider.GetCountry("BEL");
//countryInfo.Alpha2Code --> BE
```

Answer (score 3):

C# Class for All International Country code and country Name

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace International_Country_Name_And_Code
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ISO { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }

        string[][] Country = new string[][]
            {
                new string  []  { "Afghanistan",     "+93",     "AF"  },
                  new string  []  { "Albania",     "+355",     "AL"  },
                  new string  []  { "Algeria",     "+213",     "DZ"  },
                  new string  []  { "AmericanSamoa",     "+1 684",    "AS"  },
                  new string  []  { "Andorra",     "+376",     "AD"  },
                  new string  []  { "Angola",     "+244",     "AO"  },
                  new string  []  { "Anguilla",     "+1 264",     "AI"  },
                  new string  []  { "Antigua and Barbuda",     "+1268",     "AG"  },
                  new string  []  { "Argentina",     "+54",     "AR"  },
                  new string  []  { "Armenia",     "+374",     "AM"  },
                  new string  []  { "Aruba",     "+297",     "AW"  },
                  new string  []  { "Australia",     "+61",     "AU"  },
                  new string  []  { "Austria",     "+43",     "AT"  },
                  new string  []  { "Azerbaijan",     "+994",    "AZ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Bahamas",     "+1 242",     "BS"  },
                  new string  []  { "Bahrain",     "+973",     "BH"  },
                  new string  []  { "Bangladesh",     "+880",     "BD"  },
                  new string  []  { "Barbados",     "+1 246",     "BB"  },
                  new string  []  { "Belarus",     "+375",     "BY"  },
                  new string  []  { "Belgium",     "+32",     "BE"  },
                  new string  []  { "Belize",     "+501",     "BZ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Benin",     "+229",     "BJ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Bermuda",     "+1 441",     "BM"  },
                  new string  []  { "Bhutan",     "+975",     "BT"  },
                  new string  []  { "Bosnia and Herzegovina",     "+387",     "BA"  },
                  new string  []  { "Botswana",     "+267",     "BW"  },
                  new string  []  { "Brazil",     "+55",     "BR"  },
                  new string  []  { "British Indian Ocean Territory",     "+246",     "IO"  },
                  new string  []  { "Bulgaria",     "+359",     "BG"  },
                  new string  []  { "Burkina Faso",     "+226",     "BF"  },
                  new string  []  { "Burundi",     "+257",     "BI"  },
                  new string  []  { "Cambodia",     "+855",     "KH"  },
                  new string  []  { "Cameroon",     "+237",     "CM"  },
                  new string  []  { "Canada",     "+1",     "CA"  },
                  new string  []  { "Cape Verde",     "+238",     "CV"  },
                  new string  []  { "Cayman Islands",     "+ 345",     "KY"  },
                  new string  []  { "Central African Republic",     "+236",     "CF"  },
                  new string  []  { "Chad",     "+235",     "TD"  },
                  new string  []  { "Chile",     "+56",     "CL"  },
                  new string  []  { "China",     "+86",     "CN"  },
                  new string  []  { "Christmas Island",     "+61",     "CX"  },
                  new string  []  { "Colombia",     "+57",     "CO"  },
                  new string  []  { "Comoros",     "+269",     "KM"  },
                  new string  []  { "Congo",     "+242",     "CG"  },
                  new string  []  { "Cook Islands",     "+682",     "CK"  },
                  new string  []  { "Costa Rica",     "+506",     "CR"  },
                  new string  []  { "Croatia",     "+385",     "HR"  },
                  new string  []  { "Cuba",     "+53",     "CU"  },
                  new string  []  { "Cyprus",     "+537",     "CY"  },
                  new string  []  { "Czech Republic",     "+420",     "CZ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Denmark",     "+45",     "DK"  },
                  new string  []  { "Djibouti",     "+253",     "DJ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Dominica",     "+1 767",     "DM"  },
                  new string  []  { "Dominican Republic",     "+1 849",     "DO"  },
                  new string  []  { "Ecuador",     "+593",     "EC"  },
                  new string  []  { "Egypt",     "+20",     "EG"  },
                  new string  []  { "El Salvador",     "+503",     "SV"  },
                  new string  []  { "Equatorial Guinea",     "+240",     "GQ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Eritrea",     "+291",     "ER"  },
                  new string  []  { "Estonia",     "+372",     "EE"  },
                  new string  []  { "Ethiopia",     "+251",     "ET"  },
                  new string  []  { "Faroe Islands",     "+298",     "FO"  },
                  new string  []  { "Fiji",     "+679",     "FJ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Finland",     "+358",     "FI"  },
                  new string  []  { "France",     "+33",     "FR"  },
                  new string  []  { "French Guiana",     "+594",     "GF"  },
                  new string  []  { "French Polynesia",     "+689",     "PF"  },
                  new string  []  { "Gabon",     "+241",     "GA"  },
                  new string  []  { "Gambia",     "+220",     "GM"  },
                  new string  []  { "Georgia",    "+995",     "GE"  },
                  new string  []  { "Germany",     "+49",     "DE"  },
                  new string  []  { "Ghana",     "+233",     "GH"  },
                  new string  []  { "Gibraltar",     "+350",    "GI"  },
                  new string  []  { "Greece",     "+30",     "GR"  },
                  new string  []  { "Greenland",     "+299",     "GL"  },
                  new string  []  { "Grenada",     "+1 473",     "GD"  },
                  new string  []  { "Guadeloupe",     "+590",     "GP"  },
                  new string  []  { "Guam",     "+1 671",     "GU"  },
                  new string  []  { "Guatemala",     "+502",     "GT"  },
                  new string  []  { "Guinea",     "+224",     "GN"  },
                  new string  []  { "Guinea-Bissau",     "+245",     "GW"  },
                  new string  []  { "Guyana",     "+595",     "GY"  },
                  new string  []  { "Haiti",     "+509",     "HT"  },
                  new string  []  { "Honduras",     "+504",     "HN"  },
                  new string  []  { "Hungary",     "+36",     "HU"  },
                  new string  []  { "Iceland",     "+354",     "IS"  },
                  new string  []  { "India",     "+91",     "IN"  },
                  new string  []  { "Indonesia",     "+62",     "ID"  },
                  new string  []  { "Iraq",     "+964",     "IQ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Ireland",     "+353",     "IE"  },
                  new string  []  { "Israel",     "+972",     "IL"  },
                  new string  []  { "Italy",     "+39",     "IT"  },
                  new string  []  { "Jamaica",     "+1 876",     "JM"  },
                  new string  []  { "Japan",     "+81",     "JP"  },
                  new string  []  { "Jordan",     "+962",     "JO"  },
                  new string  []  { "Kazakhstan",     "+7 7",     "KZ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Kenya",     "+254",     "KE"  },
                  new string  []  { "Kiribati",     "+686",     "KI"  },
                  new string  []  { "Kuwait",     "+965",     "KW"  },
                  new string  []  { "Kyrgyzstan",     "+996",     "KG"  },
                  new string  []  { "Latvia",     "+371",     "LV"  },
                  new string  []  { "Lebanon",     "+961",     "LB"  },
                  new string  []  { "Lesotho",     "+266",     "LS"  },
                  new string  []  { "Liberia",     "+231",     "LR"  },
                  new string  []  { "Liechtenstein",     "+423",     "LI"  },
                  new string  []  { "Lithuania",     "+370",     "LT"  },
                  new string  []  { "Luxembourg",     "+352",     "LU"  },
                  new string  []  { "Madagascar",     "+261",     "MG"  },
                  new string  []  { "Malawi",     "+265",     "MW"  },
                  new string  []  { "Malaysia",     "+60",     "MY"  },
                  new string  []  { "Maldives",     "+960",     "MV"  },
                  new string  []  { "Mali",     "+223",    "ML"  },
                  new string  []  { "Malta",     "+356",     "MT"  },
                  new string  []  { "Marshall Islands",     "+692",     "MH"  },
                  new string  []  { "Martinique",     "+596",     "MQ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Mauritania",     "+222",     "MR"  },
                  new string  []  { "Mauritius",     "+230",     "MU"  },
                  new string  []  { "Mayotte",     "+262",     "YT"  },
                  new string  []  { "Mexico",     "+52",     "MX"  },
                  new string  []  { "Monaco",     "+377",     "MC"  },
                  new string  []  { "Mongolia",     "+976",     "MN"  },
                  new string  []  { "Montenegro",     "+382",     "ME"  },
                  new string  []  { "Montserrat",     "+1664",     "MS"  },
                  new string  []  { "Morocco",    "+212",     "MA"  },
                  new string  []  { "Myanmar",     "+95",     "MM"  },
                  new string  []  { "Namibia",     "+264",     "NA"  },
                  new string  []  { "Nauru",     "+674",     "NR"  },
                  new string  []  { "Nepal",     "+977",     "NP"  },
                  new string  []  { "Netherlands",     "+31",     "NL"  },
                  new string  []  { "Netherlands Antilles",     "+599",     "AN"  },
                  new string  []  { "New Caledonia",     "+687",     "NC"  },
                  new string  []  { "New Zealand",     "+64",     "NZ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Nicaragua",     "+505",     "NI"  },
                  new string  []  { "Niger",     "+227",     "NE"  },
                  new string  []  { "Nigeria",     "+234",     "NG"  },
                  new string  []  { "Niue",     "+683",     "NU"  },
                  new string  []  { "Northern Mariana Islands",     "+1670",     "MP"  },
                  new string  []  { "Norway",     "+47",     "NO"  },
                  new string  []  { "Oman",     "+968",     "OM"  },
                  new string  []  { "Pakistan",     "+92",     "PK"  },
                  new string  []  { "Palau",     "+680",     "PW"  },
                  new string  []  { "Panama",     "+507",     "PA"  },
                  new string  []  { "Papua New Guinea",     "+675",     "PG"  },
                  new string  []  { "Paraguay",     "+595",     "PY"  },
                  new string  []  { "Peru",     "+51",     "PE"  },
                  new string  []  { "Philippines",     "+63",     "PH"  },
                  new string  []  { "Poland",     "+48",     "PL"  },
                  new string  []  { "Portugal",     "+351",     "PT"  },
                  new string  []  { "Puerto Rico",    "+1939",     "PR"  },
                  new string  []  { "Qatar",     "+974",     "QA"  },
                  new string  []  { "Romania",     "+40",     "RO"  },
                  new string  []  { "Rwanda",     "+250",     "RW"  },
                  new string  []  { "Samoa",     "+685",     "WS"  },
                  new string  []  { "San Marino",     "+378",     "SM"  },
                  new string  []  { "Saudi Arabia",     "+966",     "SA"  },
                  new string  []  { "Senegal",     "+221",     "SN"  },
                  new string  []  { "Serbia",     "+381",     "RS"  },
                  new string  []  { "Seychelles",     "+248",     "SC"  },
                  new string  []  { "Sierra Leone",     "+232",     "SL"  },
                  new string  []  { "Singapore",     "+65",    "SG"  },
                  new string  []  { "Slovakia",     "+421",     "SK"  },
                  new string  []  { "Slovenia",     "+386",     "SI"  },
                  new string  []  { "Solomon Islands",     "+677",     "SB"  },
                  new string  []  { "South Africa",     "+27",     "ZA"  },
                  new string  []  { "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands",     "+500",     "GS"  },
                  new string  []  { "Spain",     "+34",     "ES"  },
                  new string  []  { "Sri Lanka",     "+94",     "LK"  },
                  new string  []  { "Sudan",     "+249",     "SD"  },
                  new string  []  { "Suriname",     "+597",     "SR"  },
                  new string  []  { "Swaziland",     "+268",     "SZ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Sweden",     "+46",     "SE"  },
                  new string  []  { "Switzerland",     "+41",     "CH"  },
                  new string  []  { "Tajikistan",     "+992",     "TJ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Thailand",     "+66",     "TH"  },
                  new string  []  { "Togo",     "+228",     "TG"  },
                  new string  []  { "Tokelau",     "+690",     "TK"  },
                  new string  []  { "Tonga",     "+676",     "TO"  },
                  new string  []  { "Trinidad and Tobago",     "+1 868",     "TT"  },
                  new string  []  { "Tunisia",     "+216",     "TN"  },
                  new string  []  { "Turkey",     "+90",     "TR"  },
                  new string  []  { "Turkmenistan",     "+993",     "TM"  },
                  new string  []  { "Turks and Caicos Islands",     "+1 649",     "TC"  },
                  new string  []  { "Tuvalu",     "+688",    "TV"  },
                  new string  []  { "Uganda",     "+256",     "UG"  },
                  new string  []  { "Ukraine",     "+380",     "UA"  },
                  new string  []  { "United Arab Emirates",     "+971",     "AE"  },
                  new string  []  { "United Kingdom",     "+44",     "GB"  },
                  new string  []  { "United States",     "+1",     "US"  },
                  new string  []  { "Uruguay",     "+598",     "UY"  },
                  new string  []  { "Uzbekistan",     "+998",     "UZ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Vanuatu",     "+678",     "VU"  },
                  new string  []  { "Wallis and Futuna",     "+681",     "WF"  },
                  new string  []  { "Yemen",     "+967",     "YE"  },
                  new string  []  { "Zambia",    "+260",     "ZM"  },
                  new string  []  { "Zimbabwe",     "+263",     "ZW"  },
                  new string  []  { "Åland Islands",     "+358",     "AX"  },
                  new string  []  { "Antarctica",     "+672",     "AQ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Bolivia, Plurinational State of",     "+591",     "BO"  },
                  new string  []  { "Brunei Darussalam",     "+673",     "BN"  },
                  new string  []  { "Cocos (Keeling) Islands",     "+61",     "CC"  },
                  new string  []  { "Congo, The Democratic Republic of the",     "+243",     "CD"  },
                  new string  []  { "Cote d'Ivoire",     "+225",     "CI"  },
                  new string  []  { "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)",     "+500",     "FK"  },
                  new string  []  { "Guernsey",     "+44",     "GG"  },
                  new string  []  { "Holy See (Vatican City State)",     "+379",     "VA"  },
                  new string  []  { "Hong Kong",     "+852",     "HK"  },
                  new string  []  { "Iran, Islamic Republic of",     "+98",     "IR"  },
                  new string  []  { "Isle of Man",     "+44",     "IM"  },
                  new string  []  { "Jersey",     "+44",     "JE"  },
                  new string  []  { "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of",     "+850",     "KP"  },
                  new string  []  { "Korea, Republic of",     "+82",     "KR"  },
                  new string  []  { "Lao People's Democratic Republic",     "+856",     "LA"  },
                  new string  []  { "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya",     "+218",     "LY"  },
                  new string  []  { "Macao",     "+853",     "MO"  },
                  new string  []  { "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of",     "+389",     "MK"  },
                  new string  []  { "Micronesia, Federated States of",     "+691",     "FM"  },
                  new string  []  { "Moldova, Republic of",     "+373",     "MD"  },
                  new string  []  { "Mozambique",     "+258",     "MZ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Palestinian Territory, Occupied",     "+970",     "PS"  },
                  new string  []  { "Pitcairn",     "+872",     "PN"  },
                  new string  []  { "Réunion",     "+262",     "RE"  },
                  new string  []  { "Russia",     "+7",     "RU"  },
                  new string  []  { "Saint Barthélemy",     "+590",     "BL"  },
                  new string  []  { "Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan Da Cunha",     "+290",     "SH"  },
                  new string  []  { "Saint Kitts and Nevis",     "+1 869",     "KN"  },
                  new string  []  { "Saint Lucia",     "+1 758",     "LC"  },
                  new string  []  { "Saint Martin",     "+590",     "MF"  },
                  new string  []  { "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",     "+508",     "PM"  },
                  new string  []  { "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",     "+1 784",     "VC"  },
                  new string  []  { "Sao Tome and Principe",     "+239",     "ST"  },
                  new string  []  { "Somalia",     "+252",     "SO"  },
                  new string  []  { "Svalbard and Jan Mayen",     "+47",     "SJ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Syrian Arab Republic",     "+963",     "SY"  },
                  new string  []  { "Taiwan, Province of China",     "+886",     "TW"  },
                  new string  []  { "Tanzania, United Republic of",     "+255",     "TZ"  },
                  new string  []  { "Timor-Leste",     "+670",     "TL"  },
                  new string  []  { "Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of",     "+58",     "VE"  },
                  new string  []  { "Viet Nam",     "+84",     "VN"  },
                  new string  []  { "Virgin Islands, British",     "+1 284",     "VG"  },
                  new string  []  { "Virgin Islands, U.S.",     "+1 340",     "VI"  }
            };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's [ISO3166](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ISO3166) Nuget package that provides list of ISO3166 countries that include name, 2 and 3 letter code, and numberic code.

Answer (score 1):

To the fellow lurker: if what you want is just to derive "default" country for a given two letter language name in .NET world (for example "**en**" => "**US**", "**ja**" => "**JP**"), this does the trick

```
// Can be read from CultureInfo.Name (or CultureInfo.Parent.Name if using non-generic culture)    
var language = "ja"; // Japanese

// Creates "ja-JP" culture 
var defaultCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);

// After this, just take the split[1] (careful, check index) to get country code
var split = defaultCulture.Name.Split('-');
```

I've this working with a JS library that accepts only ISO3166 codes, and for 25 languages our website supports this works flawlessly. Always test your scenario

Answer (score 1):

You can try using .NET **RegionInfo** as it is described [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.regioninfo.twoletterisoregionname?view=netframework-4.8):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class SamplesRegionInfo  {

   public static void Main()  {

      // Displays the property values of the RegionInfo for "US".
      RegionInfo myRI1 = new RegionInfo( "US" );
      Console.WriteLine( "   Name:                         {0}", myRI1.Name );
      Console.WriteLine( "   DisplayName:                  {0}", myRI1.DisplayName );
      Console.WriteLine( "   EnglishName:                  {0}", myRI1.EnglishName );
      Console.WriteLine( "   IsMetric:                     {0}", myRI1.IsMetric );
      Console.WriteLine( "   ThreeLetterISORegionName:     {0}", myRI1.ThreeLetterISORegionName );
      Console.WriteLine( "   ThreeLetterWindowsRegionName: {0}", myRI1.ThreeLetterWindowsRegionName );
      Console.WriteLine( "   TwoLetterISORegionName:       {0}", myRI1.TwoLetterISORegionName );
      Console.WriteLine( "   CurrencySymbol:               {0}", myRI1.CurrencySymbol );
      Console.WriteLine( "   ISOCurrencySymbol:            {0}", myRI1.ISOCurrencySymbol );

   }

}

/*
This code produces the following output.

   Name:                         US
   DisplayName:                  United States
   EnglishName:                  United States
   IsMetric:                     False
   ThreeLetterISORegionName:     USA
   ThreeLetterWindowsRegionName: USA
   TwoLetterISORegionName:       US
   CurrencySymbol:               $
   ISOCurrencySymbol:            USD

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

See Nuget package 'Bia.Countries'
https://github.com/ilyabreev/Bia.Countries done a good job with

**Bia.Countries.Iso3166.Countries.GetCountryByAlpha2()**