# Convert ISO3 country code to ISO2 country code - Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I convert ISO-3 country code to ISO-2 country code. For example, I have a string value "USA" which needs to be converted to "US".

I'm getting the 3-digit country code from API (*Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Services.MapAddress.CountryCode*) as string value, after passing *Latitude* and *Longitude* of the location. I checked Windows Phone 8 API stack but couldn't find anything relevant.

Is that possible in Windows Phone 8? Any libraries available to do the same?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are stuck with a custom mapping on WP.

The native Win NLS API which is mostly available for WP doesn't include the EnumSystemGeoID function to enumerate over all values on WP. 

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317826(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

See c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.0\Include\winnls.h :

```
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP | WINAPI_PARTITION_PC_APP)

WINBASEAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
EnumSystemGeoID(
    _In_ GEOCLASS        GeoClass,
    _In_ GEOID           ParentGeoId,
    _In_ GEO_ENUMPROC    lpGeoEnumProc);

#endif /* WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP | WINAPI_PARTITION_PC_APP) */
```

That’s likely also why the managed RegionInfo doesn’t provide that ThreeLetterISORegionName property on WP.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no built-in way to do that. You can use the approach from the [GenericTypeTea's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884692/converting-country-codes-in-net/4884803#4884803). But if you need to convert many country codes you can avoid Cultures enumeration and pre-compute a mapping dictionary for country codes conversion.

Have a look over here [Converting country codes in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884692/)

Comment: Thanks, but GenericTypeTea's answer won't work with Windows Phone 8. Though, it works with WPF.